# UV Map and Texture An Irregular, Very High Poly Object

Tags: texturing

I have a very high poly model of a product. I want to apply a simple, uniform texture over the entire object. The model is irregular, an 'S' shape. I figured out how to apply the texture using nodes, but it is not in proportion between the faces.

When I unwrap it, the UV editor shows a triangle, it appears every poly is stacked under it.

*****Please tell me there is an easy way to apply a simple repeating image texture over the entire model evenly without cutting it up, editing UVs, Etc. This thing has a ton of faces.

Notes: 
1. I am a beginner to Blender. Please provide a detailed workflow. 
2. Using Version 2.8
3. I am not afraid of doing it by hand, just need some guidance on how to tackle it.
4. I attached the pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Best,
Matt

Texture: 
[image: Texture]
     [image]

[image: UV Map Issue (Triangles)]

Comment: You don't have to use UVs to texture an object: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/texture_coordinate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to fix my issue...

I connected 'Texture Coordinates' 'Object' to 'Vector', then changed Image Texture to 'Box'. Worked like a charm. See image for node settings.

[image]